# jqPlot Duplicate values on axes

Tags: jquery, html, jqplot

I am curious if there is a way that you can keep jqPlot from duplicating values alone the axes.  I know it has to do with the size of the graph and the range of values that are being plotted.  For the Y axis I know i can just change the format to include more decimals and it will do it but the X axis is a date so that wont work.  Do you have any ideas?  here is my code if you need it:

```
$.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
              title:'Users Per Day',
              axes:{
                xaxis:{
                  renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                  tickOptions:{
                    formatString:'%b&nbsp;%#d,&nbsp;%y'
                  } 
                },
                yaxis:{
                  tickOptions:{
                    formatString:'%.1f'
                    }
                }
              },
              highlighter: {
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 7.5
              },
              cursor: {
                  show: true,
                  zoom: true,
                  showTooltip: false
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

For date values you need to use javascript timestamps in jqplot format (aka `['2012-08-21 12:00PM', 1]`) and set `tickInterval` as says in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11569531/1358777