# PrimeFaces - customise Date Chart

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, graph, primefaces, jqplot

I am using PrimeFaces 3.4.1 to plot time chart (Date on x-axis, int value on y-axis).

At the moment I have something like that:

**xhtml**:

```
<p:lineChart id="timeChart" value="#{myGraphBean.model}" legendPosition="e" title="Time Chart" minY="0" maxY="25" style="height:300px"/>
```

**Java bean**:

```
private final static int MAX_VALUE = 20;
private final static int NUMBER_OF_POINTS = 20;
private final static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");

private void createLinearModel() {
    model = new CartesianChartModel();
    Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance();
    day.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    day.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    day.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    day.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    LineChartSeries series = new LineChartSeries();
    series.setLabel("My series");
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_POINTS; i++) {
        series.set(dateFormat.format(day.getTime()), getRandomValue());
        day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
    model.addSeries(series);
}

private int getRandomValue() {
    return rand.nextInt(MAX_VALUE);
}
```

So my bean just creates some random int value for each day. (My application produces actual data points, this is just a dummy example)

In my application, I am generating data over a long time, for example 6 months. With the way I am doing things now, I get horrible graphs like that:

[image: Bad graph]

**What I would like to do:**

I'd like to be able to keep my data point but only display a tick, let's say every month.

I have tried to change the tick on the x-axis following a few other posts ([ex1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642507/primefaces-jqplot-displaying-dates-on-an-axis,), [ex2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467233/jqplot-dateaxis-tickinterval-not-working)) but I couldn't get it work.

Using the primefaces extender, I tried to use things like `tickInterval: '1 month'`, setting the `min` attributes but nothing worked. In most of the case it would just break the graph

**Questions:**

1. In the jqPlot doc, it says "*Note, although jqPlot will parse most any human readable date, it is safest to use javascript time stamps when possible. Also, it is best to specify a date and time and not just a date alone. This is due to inconsistent browser handling of local time vs. UTC with bare dates.*"
   In my graph bean, shall I populate the series using a formatted date (String) following the javascript time stamp ("yyyy-MM-dd h:mma") or using a java.util.Date directly?
2. How can I change the x-axis tick (for let's say 1 month), having a marker only every month, but still have the graph going through all the day points (i.e. I don't want to average my the points over the month)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, fill your `LineChartSeries` objects with times in milliseconds using `Date#getTime()`.

On the facelets side, download from [jqPlot site](http://www.jqplot.com) and import the following jqPlot plugins:

```
<h:outputScript name="Javascript/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js" />
<h:outputScript name="Javascript/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js" />
<h:outputScript name="Javascript/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js" />
<h:outputScript name="Javascript/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js" />
```

And use this js extender for `p:lineChart` component:

```
function chartExtender() {
    this.cfg.axes = {
        xaxis : {
            renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, 
            rendererOptions : {
                tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
            },
            tickOptions : { 
                fontSize:'10pt',
                fontFamily:'Tahoma', 
                angle:-40
            }
        },
        yaxis : {
            rendererOptions : {
                tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
            },
            tickOptions: {
                fontSize:'10pt', 
                fontFamily:'Tahoma', 
                angle:30
            }
        }               
    };
    this.cfg.axes.xaxis.ticks = this.cfg.categories;
}
```

Useful links:

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=25289#p79916

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23891&p=78637#p78637

Comment: thanks perissf. It may sound stupid but I'm not sure I managed to install jqplot. The <h:outputScript> tag that you propose cannot find the js files. I tried to download the jqplot as you suggested and tried to copy the sources in a few different places (src, src/main/ and src/main/webapp) but it didnt work.

Comment: As explained [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/), you need to create a `resources` folder in the root folder (same folder level as `WEB-INF`). Put `Javascript` folder under resources.

Comment: Thanks, it works as a charm! I still get a big marker for every data point but I should be able to get it of them using the extender.

Comment: Be welcome! Regarding the marker I was able to get rid of it, but I don't have the code with me now. In case, let me know...

Comment: Actually I might need your help :P
It's not as easy as I thought. I'm trying stuff like
this.cfg.series = {
markerRenderer: $.jqplot.MarkerRenderer,
markerOptions:{
 show: 'false'
}
};
but it's a complete guess. I'm not even sure there is a "this.cfg.series" property...

Comment: Simply use the attribute `showMarkers="false"` inside `p:lineChart`

Comment: You don't need the minified AND the non-minified JS.