# PrimeFaces OHLC chart with dates on the x-axis

Tags: date, primefaces, charts

```
OhlcChartModel model = new OhlcChartModel();

DateAxis axisX = new DateAxis("Date");

model.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axisX);

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

model.add(new OhlcChartSeries(formatter.format(seriesDate), openValue,
                  highValue, lowValue, closeValue);
```

did anyone manage to make ohlc chart work with dates ?

Comment: What **does** it do?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546153/date-axis-in-linechart-using-primefaces-and-jqplot

Answer (score 0):

It is work for me:

On java

```
         OhlcChartModel model = new OhlcChartModel();
         model.setExtender("extender");

         DateAxis xAxis = new DateAxis();       
         model.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, xAxis);
         for (Balance balance : balanceList) {
             Long date = balance.getBalanceDate().getTimeInMillis();
             double open = balance.getOpen();
             double high = balance.getHight();
             double low = balance.getLow();
             double close = balance.getClose();
             OhlcChartSeries series = new OhlcChartSeries(date, open, high, low, close);
             model.add(series);
          }
```

On javascript

```
function extender() {
this.cfg.series = [{
    renderer: $.jqplot.OHLCRenderer
}];}
```