# How to include jqplot dateAxisRenderer.min.js file in your xhtml page

Tags: javascript, xhtml, jqplot

I would like to include jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js file in your xhtml page.
How do i do ?

```
PF Version : 6.0.0
```

Added Dependency using POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>jqplot</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

How to add in xhtml file?

Following is my xhtml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

<ui:composition template="/pages/layout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="pageTitle">
        <h:outputText value="Page 3" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="centerContent">        
        <div class="contentdetailheadline parbase">    
            <h1>Page 1</h1>        
        </div>    
        <div class="bodycopy parbase">    
            <div style="clear: both"></div>    
            <div class="content-body">   
                <p>
                    Welcome to My Page !!!
                </p>  
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>    
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: Like in any of these: https://www.google.com/search?q=primefaces+jqplot+dateAxisRenderer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date axis in linechart using primefaces and jqplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546153/date-axis-in-linechart-using-primefaces-and-jqplot)