# Problems with tickInterval in jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm new to jqplot but am using it on a very important project. I am trying to have the x-axis have one 'tick' for each day -- as of now, there are multiple ones. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code (in which I also added a min and max as [this post referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467233/jqplot-dateaxis-tickinterval-not-working)):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

                            var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
                                var ret = null;
                                $.ajax({
                                    async: false,
                                    url: url,
                                    type: "GET",
                                    dataType:"json",
                                    data: {metricName: ""},
                                    success: function(data) {
                                        ret = data;
                                    },
                                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                                    }    
                                });
                                return ret;
                            };

                            //var jsonurl = "reports/reportData.json";
                            var jsonurl = "tenant/metrics/get.json";

                            var today = new Date();

                            var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
                                title: "",
                                dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
                                dataRendererOptions: {unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl},
                                axes: {
                                    xaxis: {
                                        'numberTicks' : 7,
                                        min: '2012-10-05',
                                        max: today,
                                        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                                        rendererOptions:{tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer},
                                        tickInterval: '1 day',
                                        tickOptions:{formatString:'%Y-%#m-%#d'

                                        }
                                        //rendererOptions: {sdaTickInterval: [1, 'month']}

                                    },
                                    yaxis: {
                                        label: "MB",
                                        tickOptions:{formatString:'%d '},
                                        // Comment the next line out to allow negative values (and therefore rounded ones)
                                        min: 0
                                    }
                                }   
                            });
                        });
```

Even if I manually set the clicks like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

                            var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
                                var ret = null;
                                $.ajax({
                                    async: false,
                                    url: url,
                                    type: "GET",
                                    dataType:"json",
                                    data: {metricName: ""},
                                    success: function(data) {
                                        ret = data;
                                    },
                                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                                    }    
                                });
                                return ret;
                            };

                            //var jsonurl = "reports/reportData.json";
                            var jsonurl = "tenant/metrics/get.json";

                            var today = new Date();

                            var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
                                title: "",
                                dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
                                dataRendererOptions: {unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl},
                                axes: {
                                    xaxis: {
                                        'numberTicks' : 7,
                                        min: '2012-10-05',
                                        max: today,
                                        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                                        rendererOptions:{tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer},
                                        ticks: ['2012-10-05','2012-10-06','2012-10-07','2012-10-08', today],
                                        tickOptions:{formatString:'%Y-%#m-%#d'

                                        }
                                        //rendererOptions: {sdaTickInterval: [1, 'month']}

                                    },
                                    yaxis: {
                                        label: "MB",
                                        tickOptions:{formatString:'%d '},
                                        // Comment the next line out to allow negative values (and therefore rounded ones)
                                        min: 0
                                    }
                                }   
                            });
                        });
```

The marks do not match up to their correct dates. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Is there a sane way to do this? I want each x-axis tick to be only one date, and the data entry mark to be on that tick's axis.

This is driving me crazy! Please help!

Also, here is my json

```
[[["2012-10-05 10:57:16AM", 0],["2012-10-05 11:02:14AM", 2449],["2012-10-08 08:17:47AM", 9639],["2012-10-08 08:17:53AM", 224768],["2012-10-09 07:43:19AM", 9640],["2012-10-09 07:44:01AM", 224769]]]
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON; I would wager that your issue may lay there.

Comment: Just posted. Does it help at all? Maybe the timestamps are throwing it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string isn't correct as it doesn't include the timestamp; try changing it to the following:

```
tickOptions:{formatString:'%y-%#m-%#d%n%#I:%#M:%#S%p}
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the timestamp, leave your format string as is and remove the timestamp from the JSON.

**EDIT**

If the above format string doesn't work, try manipulating the values to match using the values as below:

```
// Year
%Y  2008
%y  08

// Month
%m  09
%#m  9
%B  September
%b  Sep

// Day
%d  05
%#d  5
%e  5
%A  Sunday
%a  Sun
%w  0, 0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday
%o  th, The ordinal suffix string following the day of the month

// Hour
%H  23
%#H  3
%I   11
%#I  3
%p  PM, AM or PM

// Minute
%M  09
%#M  9

// Second
%S  02
%#S  2
%s  1206567625723, Unix timestamp, seconds past 1970-01-01 00:00:00

// Millisecond
%N  008
%#N  8
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This very much helped, and sent me on the right path! The main issue was in the fact that the timestamps were making the grid 'too accurate' in a sense, since I only wanted them to fall on exact dates. So, I had to change things on the server-side/JSON so timestamps wouldn't be in the incoming JSON, and then change the max/min dates in the JS so they didn't include timestamps. Thank you for all your help!