# jqplot xaxis tickInterval as minute or second

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am using the jquery jqplot plugin. 
I have an issue about setting tickInterval.
I would like to show X axis values between 10:00 and 12:00 by one minute difference such as 10:01, 10:02, 10:03,...,11:59.
For this purpose, I've written this code.

```
var data = [['10:55', 578.55], ['11:02', 566.5], ['11:04', 480.88], ['11:08', 509.84],
                      ['11:12', 454.13], ['11:22', 379.75], ['11:33', 303], ['11:39', 308.56],
                      ['11:41', 299.14], ['11:52', 346.51], ['11:54', 325.99], ['11:56', 386.15]];
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [data], {
            title: 'Average Response Time Graphic - Last One Hour By Minute',
            axes: {
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                labelOptions:{
                    fontFamily:'Helvetica',
                    fontSize: '14pt'
                },
                xaxis: {
                    label : "Time",
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    <!--tickOptions:{formatString:'%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S', angle: -30},-->
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString:'%H:%M:%S', 
                        angle: -30,
                        tickInterval : '1 minute'
                        <!--tickInterval : '60000' -->
                    },

                    <!--min: '2013-02-05 10:50', -->
                    min: '10:00',
                    max: '12:00'
                },
                yaxis: {
                    label: "Average Response Time",
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '$%.2f'
                    }
                }
            },
            highlighter: {
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 7.5
            },
            cursor: {
                show: false
            }
        });
```

However, this code doesnt work very well since there is 10 minute difference between x axis values between 10:00 and 12:00.
By the way, I've added all jqplot plugin files not to cause wrong evaluation of javascript.

I've looked at this issue [jqPlot DateAxis tickInterval not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467233/jqplot-dateaxis-tickinterval-not-working) and tried the first answer, however it doesnt work, too.

Is there anyone who may help me to solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance,

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution! It worked when I remove tickInterval from tickOptions and put under xaxis !